# Придаточное времени или изъяснительное?

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, выделенное предложение придаточное времени или изъяснительное? 
Как надо правильно задавать вопрос: ждал чего? или ждал какого момента?

*Я сидел и ждал, **пока она придет с работы**.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это придаточное **изъяснительное**, ПОКА (=КОГДА) является союзным словом. В общем случае изъяснительное грамматическое значение определяется **по семантике опорного слова**, в данном случае глагол "ждать" имеет значение восприятия, целенаправленного наблюдения.

Для сравнения: общим грамматическим значением **для придаточных времени** является временное соотношение двух ситуаций.

Comment: Sibylla, большое Вам спасибо за ответ! в таком случае "Он сидел и ждал – не раздастся ли стук в дверь." это тоже изъяснительное придаточное? знак препинания ведь не играет существенной роли?

Comment: Думаю, что в данном случае вместо запятой в СПП с придаточным изъяснительным используется авторское тире, обозначающее увеличенную паузу. В то же время надо помнить, что СПП и БСП часто синонимичны по значению и могут быть преобразованы одно в другое, например: (1) Она еще жила в родительском доме, еще ждала, придет ли, наконец, Савченко (И. Г. Эренбург). (2) Под бурями судьбы жестокой Увял цветущий мой венец; Живу печальный, одинокий, И жду: придет ли мой конец? (А.С. Пушкин).

Comment: В БСП частица ЛИ является вопросительной (стоит знак вопроса), а в СПП частица ЛИ  выполняет функцию подчинительного союза (знака вопроса нет). Вообще говоря, при наличии частицы ЛИ чаще встречаются предложения, оформленные как СПП (с запятой и без знака вопроса).

Comment: большое спасибо!!! : )